# is there a way to have an exception handled the same way every time without skipping much code

Tags: java, try-catch, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a simple Game of life code and I have to use thousands of try catch statements for out of bounds exceptions with empty catch statements for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Is there a way to tell the program to handle all of one exception the same way? Is having thousands of try catch statements hard on the cpu?

Comment: You shouldn't be catching ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. It's not required to catch, and there are proper ways to avoid it being thrown in the first place (such as checking array index bounds).

Answer (score 3):

**Thousands**!?

Alright, things you need to know about `try/catch`: they are very, very, very expensive for the CPU, they slow down your program like crazy, and they should *only* be used for situations where there is a possibility something might fail and you need to do some special handling if it does.

You're definitely doing something wrong with your design, but without a code sample I'm guessing that you're not checking the size of the array when you iterate through it which is...just awful, honestly.

In Java, we can do things like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {}
```

or:

```
for(Integer i : arr) {}
```

These guarantee that you'll never exceed the bounds of the array (so long as your program isn't modifying the array inside the loop).

You should never, ever, EVER be seeing `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exceptions over the course of iterating through a fixed length array. You *know* the length of the array, why not use it?

Comment: Are you sure they're very (very very) expensive for the CPU? I was under the impression they're actually very lightweight until an exception is thrown, and even then they're not really more expensive than, say, an `if` statement.

Comment: My impression is that as you said, a `try` has very little overhead in and of itself, but with thousands of try/catches as posted above, it adds up. And, if any of those out of bounds exceptions gets thrown, the exception throwing is very expensive because Java is a JIT virtual machine: code is fastest when it runs the same way every time. As a programmer, the blanket statement "avoid try/catch if you can" is not bad advice, and in general it incurs performance penalties.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Throwing and catching exceptions is not particularly expensive. Constructing exception objects with stack traces is extremely expensive.